# Transistor level netlist benchmarks

Tags: routing, vlsi, library, modeling, eda

I'm PhD student in CAD/EDA field. My research topic covers VLSI standard cell's layout design and detailed routing. To make my research results more reliable, I would like to test proposed algorithm with some recognizable benchmarks/cell libraries. But, suddenly, I'm not able to find anything of use, except for [NanGate FreePDK15](https://www.si2.org/openeda.si2.org/projects/nangatelib).

So, are there any publicly available standard cell library benchmarks, which contain transistor level description of various gates (like aoi222, nand44, fad1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this in the comments, but it's too long.

For research purposes, I always just make my own because I can publish over them.  I have commercial libraries as well, but there's a no publish clause that is in the contracts.  You might be able to get someone to supply you with something for the larger nodes.  http://www.vlsitechnology.org/ might get you started.

On the side of practicality, a single library might be fine if you are just looking at graph routing because the details generally do not have to know anything about the cell but the ports.  The routers just locate the pins and then route the graphs.  You might do better to just make a "pin matrix" tool that then routes the wires, and then you can narrow down if/why/what is the best pin placement for the standard cells.  You can simulate these just by doing the layout wire extraction and the circuit netlist.

If you are dead set on standard cells, and have access to the Cadence/Synopsys tool chain, I would suggest emailing [Dr.Mooney](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mooney/) at Georgia Tech and as him for "Phil's" document for creating and analyzing standard cells.  I cannot recall Phil's name, but we have extensive documentation for creating, testing, comparing standard cells that I used extensively in my time as a grad student.  Dr. Mooney's advisor started Synopsys, so standard cells and routing are sort of his speciality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I stuck with standard cells - my research problem can't be reduced to a graph task. Probably, I'll make my own semi-artificial lib.

Comment: I have had excellent success in research because I supply the complete code to reproduce all of my data.  Making your own cells will likely benefit you in this way too because you can just cite your cells in your paper.  I promise you that it's worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide some feedback on this question.

Eventually, I end up using the following process: [FreePDK15](http://www.eda.ncsu.edu/wiki/FreePDK15:Contents) and corresponding [standard cell library](http://www.nangate.com/?page_id=22) as a reference or 'golden' design. It's not perfect, it is very simplistic, but it is good enough. In my case, I'll probably use this PDK with some changes (mostly in design rules) in my own research. In addition, there are a few articles on the process itself and on the cell library, which describe all decisions about cell architecture and design constraints.

Comment: I'll be interested in your results.  Post a link here when it's finished.... in 3 years. :)

Comment: I plan to finish my research next winter. So it's only about 10 months.)

Comment: The article is finally [published](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7807654/). A little bit later I'll post the whole text somewhere.